# Issue on route when using render_views method on rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, tdd, rendering

I am starting to learning about TDD on Ruby on Rails and I'm having these issues that I can't solve, I getting this routing problem when I use the render_views method to check if there is data on the view. (It's working without problem with the render_views method out)

```
Failures:

  1) CachorrosController GET index ter a variável de classe @cachorros
 Failure/Error: get :index

 SyntaxError:
   /vagrant/Aulas - Torne-se um programador/app_gem/app/views/cachorros/index.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
   /vagrant/Aulas - Torne-se um programador/app_gem/app/views/cachorros/index.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
 # ./spec/controllers/cachorros_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) CachorrosController GET index esta rota precisa renderizar o template index
 Failure/Error: get :index

 SyntaxError:
   /vagrant/Aulas - Torne-se um programador/app_gem/app/views/cachorros/index.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
   /vagrant/Aulas - Torne-se um programador/app_gem/app/views/cachorros/index.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
 # ./spec/controllers/cachorros_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) CachorrosController GET index verifica se o código foi inserido na página
 Failure/Error: get :index

 SyntaxError:
   /vagrant/Aulas - Torne-se um programador/app_gem/app/views/cachorros/index.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
   /vagrant/Aulas - Torne-se um programador/app_gem/app/views/cachorros/index.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.4/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
 # ./spec/controllers/cachorros_controller_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.28037 seconds (files took 5.17 seconds to load)
10 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/cachorros_controller_spec.rb:7 # CachorrosController GET index ter a variável de classe @cachorros
rspec ./spec/controllers/cachorros_controller_spec.rb:15 # CachorrosController GET index esta rota precisa renderizar o template index
rspec ./spec/controllers/cachorros_controller_spec.rb:20 # CachorrosController GET index verifica se o código foi inserido na página
```

This is the spec/controllers/cachorros_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CachorrosController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET index" do
    render_views

    it "ter a variável de classe @cachorros" do
      Cachorro.destroy_all
      cachorro = Cachorro.create(nome: "Boomer", raca: "Beagle")
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:cachorros)).to eq([cachorro])
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end

    it "esta rota precisa renderizar o template index" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end

    it "verifica se o código foi inserido na página" do
      Cachorro.destroy_all
      cachorro = Cachorro.create(nome: "Boomer", raca: "Beagle")
      get :index
      expect(response.body).to match /<ul>.?*<li>/im
    end
  end
end
```

This is the views/cachorros/index.html.erb:

```
<ul>
  <% @cachorros.each do |cachorro| %>
  <li> <%= @cachorro.nome %></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Non-English posts are generally flagged as _unclear what you're asking_. You can read more [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/3784008) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262015/3784008). If you can translate your question to English you are much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Please, add views/cachorros/index.html.erb to the question.

Comment: View added @Vasilisa, just a simple each for the test

Answer (score 0):

It is missing `end` for iteration

```
<ul>
  <% @cachorros.each do |cachorro| %>
    <li> <%= @cachorro.nome %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```